# WooCommerce Hook to Trigger Email in Refund inside Email Class

Tags: email, woocommerce

By default, WooCommerce does not send Refund emails because refunding is, as Mike Jolley says, "a manual process". However, I need to send one!

My problem is: I can't find a hook that will fire inside my extended email class to do this.

I followed this tutorial, wrote a class to extend `WC_Email` and got everything working *except* that I need a hook to trigger the class when an order status is changed and saved as "refunded":

http://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/

I tried various hooks like `woocommerce_order_status_refund` in place of the `woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_notification` hook on line 39-40.

The problem is that `woocommerce_order_status_refund` doesn't trigger inside email class. It works fine elsewhere, but not in this context.

I tried replacing the hook with `woocommerce_order_actions_end` as a sort of "generic". I added an if `(! $order->status == 'refunded')` to filter for "refunded" only. But now the hook fired every time an order with a status of 'refunded' is loaded.

(I also tried adding a custom action with woocommerce_order_actions to the actions menu, but the problem is here I don't know how to trigger my class with this. It seems to load before the class so that doesn't work either.)

Is there any way to trigger an email send via an extended class only when order status is changed to 'refunded'?

Answer (score 1):

Referencing this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25544762/383847) there are two things you must do to get the refund status to trigger an email.

First you must register the `woocommerce_order_status_refunded` hook as a hook that will trigger an email. By default, it does not.

```
/**
 * Register the "woocommerce_order_status_refunded" hook which is necessary to
 * allow automatic email notifications when the order is changed to refunded.
 * 
 * @modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26413223/2078474 to remove anonymous function
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'so_25353766_register_email' );
function so_25353766_register_email(){
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_refunded', array( WC(), 'send_transactional_email' ), 10, 10 );
}
```

**EDIT for WooCommerce 2.3**

After merging in my pull request, the next version of WooCommerce (2.3) should support filtering of the actions that trigger emails. So you would add the refund status via filter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_init', 'so_26483961_filter_email_actions' );
function so_26483961_filter_email_actions( $emails ){
    $emails[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_refunded';
    return $emails;
}
```

Then in your custom email class's `_construct` method, you can use this as the trigger:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_refunded', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );
```