# WooCommerce - send custom email on custom order status change

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I added a custom status `wc-order-confirmed`:

```
// Register new status
function register_order_confirmed_order_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-order-confirmed', array(
        'label' => 'Potvrzení objednávky',
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count' => _n_noop( 'Potvrzení objednávky <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Potvrzení objednávky <span class="count">(%s)</span>' )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_order_confirmed_order_status' );

// Add to list of WC Order statuses
function add_order_confirmed_to_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $new_order_statuses = array();
// add new order status after processing
    foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {
        $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;
        if ( 'wc-processing' === $key ) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-order-confirmed'] = 'Potvrzení objednávky';
        }
    }
    return $new_order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_order_confirmed_to_order_statuses' );
```

I added a custom email `wc_confirmed_order`:

```
/**
 * A custom confirmed Order WooCommerce Email class
 *
 * @since 0.1
 * @extends \WC_Email
 */
class WC_Confirmed_Order_Email extends WC_Email {


    /**
     * Set email defaults
     *
     * @since 0.1
     */
    public function __construct() {

        // set ID, this simply needs to be a unique name
        $this->id = 'wc_confirmed_order';

        // this is the title in WooCommerce Email settings
        $this->title = 'Potvrzení objednávky';

        // this is the description in WooCommerce email settings
        $this->description = 'Confirmed Order Notification';

        // these are the default heading and subject lines that can be overridden using the settings
        $this->heading = 'Potvrzení objednávky';
        $this->subject = 'Potvrzení objednávky';

        // these define the locations of the templates that this email should use, we'll just use the new order template since this email is similar
        $this->template_html  = 'emails/customer-confirmed-order.php';
        $this->template_plain = 'emails/plain/admin-new-order.php';

        // Trigger on confirmed orders
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_order_confirmed', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_order_confirmed', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );

        // Call parent constructor to load any other defaults not explicity defined here
        parent::__construct();

        // this sets the recipient to the settings defined below in init_form_fields()
        $this->recipient = $this->get_option( 'recipient' );

        // if none was entered, just use the WP admin email as a fallback
        if ( ! $this->recipient )
            $this->recipient = get_option( 'admin_email' );
    }


    /**
     * Determine if the email should actually be sent and setup email merge variables
     *
     * @since 0.1
     * @param int $order_id
     */
    public function trigger( $order_id ) {
            // bail if no order ID is present
        if ( ! $order_id )
            return;

        if ( $order_id ) {
            $this->object       = wc_get_order( $order_id );
            $this->recipient    = $this->object->billing_email;

            $this->find['order-date']      = '{order_date}';
            $this->find['order-number']    = '{order_number}';

            $this->replace['order-date']   = date_i18n( wc_date_format(), strtotime( $this->object->order_date ) );
            $this->replace['order-number'] = $this->object->get_order_number();
        }


        if ( ! $this->is_enabled() || ! $this->get_recipient() )
            return;

        // woohoo, send the email!
        $this->send( $this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
    }


    /**
     * get_content_html function.
     *
     * @since 0.1
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_content_html() {
        ob_start();
        wc_get_template( $this->template_html, array(
            'order'         => $this->object,
            'email_heading' => $this->get_heading()
        ) );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }


    /**
     * get_content_plain function.
     *
     * @since 0.1
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_content_plain() {
        ob_start();
        wc_get_template( $this->template_plain, array(
            'order'         => $this->object,
            'email_heading' => $this->get_heading()
        ) );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }


    /**
     * Initialize Settings Form Fields
     *
     * @since 2.0
     */
    public function init_form_fields() {

        $this->form_fields = array(
            'enabled'    => array(
                'title'   => 'Enable/Disable',
                'type'    => 'checkbox',
                'label'   => 'Enable this email notification',
                'default' => 'yes'
            ),
            'recipient'  => array(
                'title'       => 'Recipient(s)',
                'type'        => 'text',
                'description' => sprintf( 'Enter recipients (comma separated) for this email. Defaults to <code>%s</code>.', esc_attr( get_option( 'admin_email' ) ) ),
                'placeholder' => '',
                'default'     => ''
            ),
            'subject'    => array(
                'title'       => 'Subject',
                'type'        => 'text',
                'description' => sprintf( 'This controls the email subject line. Leave blank to use the default subject: <code>%s</code>.', $this->subject ),
                'placeholder' => '',
                'default'     => ''
            ),
            'heading'    => array(
                'title'       => 'Email Heading',
                'type'        => 'text',
                'description' => sprintf( __( 'This controls the main heading contained within the email notification. Leave blank to use the default heading: <code>%s</code>.' ), $this->heading ),
                'placeholder' => '',
                'default'     => ''
            ),
            'email_type' => array(
                'title'       => 'Email type',
                'type'        => 'select',
                'description' => 'Choose which format of email to send.',
                'default'     => 'html',
                'class'       => 'email_type',
                'options'     => array(
                    'plain'     => __( 'Plain text', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'html'      => __( 'HTML', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'multipart' => __( 'Multipart', 'woocommerce' ),
                )
            )
        );
    }


} // end \WC_confirmed_Order_Email class
```

I can see the email in the email settings, and the status in the order statuses dropdown. Now, I need to send my new email whenever the order status is changed to `wc-order-confirmed`. The transition hook seems to never be firing.

I also tried:

```
/**
 * Register the "woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_quote" hook which is necessary to
 * allow automatic email notifications when the order is changed to refunded.
 *
 * @modified from http://stackoverflow.com/a/26413223/2078474 to remove anonymous function
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'so_25353766_register_email' );
function so_25353766_register_email(){
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_order_confirmed', array( WC(), 'send_transactional_email' ), 10, 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_order_confirmed', array( WC(), 'send_transactional_email' ), 10, 10 );
}
```

Which also doesn't seem to work at all... Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Xcid's answer indicates, you need to register the email.

In WC 2.2+ I believe you can do this via the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-order-confirmed', array( WC(), 'send_transactional_email' ), 10, 10 );
```

I'd added a filter to WooCommerce 2.3, so when that comes out custom emails will be able to be added to the list of email actions that WooCommerce registers:

```
// As of WooCommerce 2.3
function so_27112461_woocommerce_email_actions( $actions ){
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-order-confirmed';
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'so_27112461_woocommerce_email_actions' );
```

Answer (score 26):

The hook you need is:

**woocommerce_order_status_changed**

```
add_action("woocommerce_order_status_changed", "my_awesome_publication_notification");

function my_awesome_publication_notification($order_id, $checkout=null) {
   global $woocommerce;
   $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
   if($order->status === 'completed' ) {
      // Create a mailer
      $mailer = $woocommerce->mailer();

      $message_body = __( 'Hello world!!!' );

      $message = $mailer->wrap_message(
        // Message head and message body.
        sprintf( __( 'Order %s received' ), $order->get_order_number() ), $message_body );


      // Cliente email, email subject and message.
     $mailer->send( $order->billing_email, sprintf( __( 'Order %s received' ), $order->get_order_number() ), $message );
     }

   }
}
```

Comment: Best and Simple solution. Thanks

Comment: the hook is correct and works. you can send mails on any status change even if the order status is just created as "on-hold". the wc()->mailer is using the php mail class, so you even can use the wp_mail function to send mails and adding attachments etc. quite simple to use if you know how to send mails with php script.

Answer (score 6):

As you can see here : 
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/f8a161c40673cb019eb96b04c04a774ca040a15a/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php#L2097
you can use this hook :

`do_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_' . $new_status, $this->id );`

with you custom status should give :

`add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-order-confirmed' , array( $this, 'trigger' ) );`

I imagine that you also add you custom email to the mailer, if not :

just add :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', array($this,'edit_woocommerce_email_classes' ));
function edit_woocommerce_email_classes( $email_classes ) {
    require_once( 'your-email-class.php' );
    $email_classes[ 'WC_Confirmed_Order_Email' ] = new WC_Confirmed_Order_Email();
    return $email_classes;
 }
```

Edit :

You need to instanciate woocommerce emails before so you can add

```
add_action( 'init' , 'initiate_woocommerce_email' );

function initiate_woocommerce_email(){
   // Just when you update the order_status on backoffice
   if( isset($_POST['order_status']) ) {
        WC()->mailer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising! What do you mean by adding WC()->mailer() ?

Comment: WC()->mailer() is an internal woocommerce function that instanciate woocommerce emails service, in other words the function will instanciate your custom class.

Comment: Yup, I understand the WC()->mailer() should instanciate my class, but I'm not sure where to put it? You mean to add it to the `woocommerce_order_status_wc-order-confirmed` action or where?

Comment: You add a custom status, when do you change de status ? Manually? On the back office ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to watch when the order status changed so put this into functions.php:

```
function confirmed_notifications($order_id, $checkout=null) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    if( $order->status === 'order-confirmed' ) {

        // Trigger transactional email to client
        $email = $mailer->emails['WC_Confirmed_Order_Email'];
        $email->trigger( $order_id );
    }
}
add_action("woocommerce_order_status_changed", "confirmed_notifications");
```

This function will trigger your email and send it.