# woocommerce_email_actions not working in custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to send a email when a order is moved to a custom status in woocommerce. I have successfully created a plugin that creates a custom status and order is assigned to the custom status.

I have also successfully added a custom email template under Settings -> Emails in WooCommerce and written code which should send a email when the order is moved to that custom status.

However that code is not getting triggered and email is not getting sent.

Below is my code.

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_actions', array('woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_partial-shipment'));


// Trigger on new paid orders
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_partial-shipment_notification',  array( $this, 'trigger' ) );
```

the action never comes in the trigger function i have written. I am using wordpress 4.5.3 and woocommerce version 2.6.4.

Can anyone suggest as to what could be going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WooCommerce - send custom email on custom order status change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112461/woocommerce-send-custom-email-on-custom-order-status-change)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27122473/383847)

Answer (score 1):

Since WooCommerce 2.3, you can use 'woocommerce_email_actions' filter, so you can try this:

```
function new_woocommerce_email_actions( $actions ){
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_processing_to_partial-shipment_notification';
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'new_woocommerce_email_actions' );
```

Luck