# Filter woocommerce_email_actions

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, hook

I am currently trying to add new custom emails to the woocommerce emails list.
I have followed the instructions from this link : https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/

I use a custom action for this email (*ch_deadline*) which I trigger with this in my plugin:

```
add_action( 'ch_deadline_notification', array( $this, 'trigger' ) );
```

As I have seen in this post : [WooCommerce - send custom email on custom order status change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112461/woocommerce-send-custom-email-on-custom-order-status-change), I need to add it to the woocommerce email actions :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'add_deadline_email_actions' ); // WC 2.3+
function add_deadline_email_actions( $email_actions ) {
   $email_actions[] = 'ch_deadline';
   return $email_actions;
}
```

In the front-end, it works well, it display my new email in the list.
Unfortunately the email has never been sent.
I have read a lot of post about this problem but none of the proposed solutions resolved the problem

I have even tried to add directly my action in *$email_actions* list in *class-wc-emails.php*

If you have any ideas, I'm more than interested !

Thanks !

Comment: `ch_deadline_notification` is not the same as `ch_deadline`. Make sure they match and make sure that `ch_deadline_notification` is being triggered somewhere.

Comment: Did you ever solved this?