# Custom WordPress E-mail in WooCommerce Format

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am interested in creating a custom email that is formatted in the same format as all WooCommerce emails. The goal of this plugin will be to send emails to clients on the happening of specific events, such as when a order is cancelled. Unfortunately the basic wp_mail function do not have consistent Woocommerce mail formatting applied.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you elaborate how this question is different from any of the other questions about WooCommerce emails related to order status changes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WooCommerce - send custom email on custom order status change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112461/woocommerce-send-custom-email-on-custom-order-status-change)