# Get ACF custom fields values in woocommerce custom email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

If the user Woocommerce changes his data, a mail to the administrator receives a email about these changes.

I need to show in this letter the custom fields that I created in the ACF. (In ACF created a questionnaire and put it into a /edit-account)

Here is the complete code, based on - [Send notification email when customer changes address WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270846/send-notification-email-when-customer-changes-address-woocommerce/32389493#32389493)

```
if( !class_exists('WooCommerceNotifyChanges') ){

class WooCommerceNotifyChanges{

function __construct(){
    // customer saves main account data
    add_action('woocommerce_save_account_details', array( $this, 'woocommerce_send_notification' ));
}

function woocommerce_send_notification(){
    $body       = '';
    $to         = 'email@domain.com';    //address that will receive this email
    $subject    = 'One of your customers has updated their information.';

    $curr_user      = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id        = $curr_user->ID;
    $curr_username  = $curr_user->data->user_login;

    $body .= '<table>';
    $body .= '<tr><td><strong>Account</strong></td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Username: </td><td>' . $curr_username                                         . '</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>First name: </td><td>' . get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_first_name', true ). '</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Last name: </td><td>' . get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_last_name', true )  . '</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Phone: </td><td>' . get_field('user_phone') . '</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Age: </td><td>' . get_field('user_age') . '</td></tr>';
    $body .= '</table>';    

    //set content type as HTML
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;');

}
} new WooCommerceNotifyChanges(); 
}
```

Unfortunately, the custom field is not displayed. All fields in my account have been filled in, I received a email about changing the user's data. But custom fields are not shown in the email.

I tried the option:

```
$body .= '<tr><td>Phone: </td><td>' . get_field('user_phone', 'user_1') . '</td></tr>';
$body .= '<tr><td>Phone: </td><td>' . get_field('user_phone', $user_id) . '</td></tr>';
```

I will be happy with your help.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't use logically `wp_get_current_user()` for email notifications or backend orders, as there is no a current user anymore.

But if you have a look to [`woocommerce_save_account_details` hook source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Form_Handler.html#291) you will notice **that `$user_id` is passed as a hook argument** and you can use it in the related function, as following:

```
if( !class_exists('WooCommerceNotifyChanges') ){
    class WooCommerceNotifyChanges{

        function __construct(){
            // customer saves main account data
            add_action('woocommerce_save_account_details', array( $this, 'woocommerce_send_notification' ), 15, 1 );
        }

        function woocommerce_send_notification( $user_id ){
            $body      = '';
            $to        = 'email@domain.com';    //address that will receive this email
            $subject   = 'One of your customers has updated their information.';

            $user      = new WP_User( $user_id );
            $user_name = $user->user_login;

            $body .= '<table>';
            $body .= '<tr><td><strong>' . __("Account") . '</strong></td></tr>';
            $body .= '<tr><td>Username: </td><td>' . $user_name                                         . '</td></tr>';
            $body .= '<tr><td>First name: </td><td>' . $user->billing_first_name . '</td></tr>';
            $body .= '<tr><td>Last name: </td><td>' . $user->billing_last_name  . '</td></tr>';
            $body .= '<tr><td>Phone: </td><td>' . get_field( 'user_phone', $user_id ) . '</td></tr>';
            $body .= '<tr><td>Age: </td><td>' . get_field( 'user_age', $user_id ) . '</td></tr>';
            $body .= '</table>';    

            //set content type as HTML
            $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;');
        }
    } 
    new WooCommerceNotifyChanges(); 
}
```

Now it should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, the fields 'user_phone' and 'user_age' are not shown. These custom fields are created and correct. They are displayed in the my-account. In the email, no. What could be the problem?

Comment: @dimitry, It depends where they are activated and how they are saved. So you should try to update your question with that information (and may be some screenshots of their settings)… **We can not  guess** what you are doing and how, regarding those 2 ACF fields. Remember that *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**"*.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the settings:
[link](https://prnt.sc/kfjx0b)

I created a new field. This field is shown and saved, but the email is not displayed.
`$body .= '<tr><td>Phone: </td><td>' . get_field( 'user_new_phone', $user_id ) . '</td></tr>';
`

Comment: @Dimitry You should update your question with this, instead of adding it as a comment. I can't do anything more as this is related to your own ACF settings and saving data. Something is wrong with the user ID that is used to saved the ACF fields values...

Answer (score 0):

To get fields from a user record in ACF you don't just pass the user's ID, you have to pass it in a string prepended with "user_", so the string should be: `"user_{$user_id}"` and the whole thing would therefore be `get_field( 'user_age', "user_{$user_id}" )`

See the docs: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/