# How to show the fields of ACF in email?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, email-notifications

If the user Woocommerce changes his data, a mail to the administrator receives a email about these changes.

I need to show in this letter the custom fields that I created in the ACF. (In ACF created a questionnaire and put it into a /edit-account)

Here is the complete code, based on - [Get ACF custom fields values in woocommerce custom email notification.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715532/get-acf-custom-fields-values-in-woocommerce-custom-email-notification)

```
if( !class_exists('WooCommerceNotifyChanges') ){

class WooCommerceNotifyChanges{

function __construct(){
    // customer saves main account data
    add_action('woocommerce_save_account_details', array( $this, 'woocommerce_send_notification' ), 15, 1 );

}

function woocommerce_send_notification( $user_id ){
    $body       = '';
    $to         = 'info@domain.com';    //address that will receive this email
    $subject    = 'One of your customers has updated their information.';

    $user      = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $user_name = $user->user_login;

    $body .= '<table>';
    $body .= '<tr><td><strong>' . __("Account") . '</strong></td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Username: </td><td>' . $user_name                                         . '</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>First name: </td><td>' . $user->billing_first_name . '</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Last name: </td><td>' . $user->billing_last_name  . '</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Phone: </td><td>' . get_field( 'user_phone', 'user_{$user_id}' ) . '</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Age: </td><td>' . get_field( 'user_age', 'user_{$user_id}' ) . '</td></tr>';
    $body .= '</table>';    

    //set content type as HTML
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;');

    //send email
    if( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers ) ){
        //echo 'email sent';
    }else{
        //echo 'email NOT sent';                
    }
    //exit();
}
}
new WooCommerceNotifyChanges(); 
}
```

Unfortunately, the fields 'user_phone' and 'user_age' are not shown. These custom fields are created and correct. They are displayed in the my-account. In the email, no.

Here is a screenshot of the settings ACF [image: image here]

[image: My Account (screenshot)]

I wrote even so, but the field does not appear:

```
get_field( 'user_phone', $user_id )
```

Comment: Does $user_id actually contain an ID?

Comment: How do I find out?

Comment: Try and echo out $user_id - what does it return

Comment: As the `$user_id` works, **because it's a hook argument**, you should try to test `get_field( 'user_phone', 75 ), with the  real user ID (a numerical value instead of a dynamic variable) to see if you get some output. If not that means that ACF is not saving any value.

Comment: `get_field( 'user_phone', 13)` user_id13 produces an empty result ((

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I created fields in the AСF plugin. I placed the fields in my account (see screenshot). In the file functions.php added the code that you see above. Maybe I need to add additional code to the functions.php? For example, to register fields, etc.?

Comment: ACF is about settings and your problem come from ACF as you have noticed. Where are they in my account? Can you show us a screenshot with the displayed fields in my  account? Are the fields saving values? A screenshot of the settings is not really useful. You need to have displayed fields that save entered values… if not ask in ACF support pages.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I added a screenshot to my post. All fields are displayed and saved. But for some reason they are not shown in the email ((

Comment: @Dmitry As ACF is about settings (and not coding) I don't know what is your problem and I can't reproduce, check anything and find what is wrong in your case.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec And can you test yourself? I use the ACF PRO and "Advanced Custom Fields for WooCommerce".

Comment: @Dmitry If I could I have already answered that question. The other alternative should be to use normal custom fields instead. That way anyone can test and give you an answer if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into it and `wp_user_meta()` is just a wrapper for `get_metadata()`, and `get_metadata()` **caches its results**. If have make edits to your WP User earlier in the exection, it gets cached. Then, later you want to send this email, you will you already have a "cached" version of the user saved in memory, and those are the values you have returned.

You can bust the cache by putting this at the top of your hook:

`update_meta_cache( 'user', $user_id );`

This should bust the cache so when you do:

`get_user_meta($user_id, 'field_5b7e4f388fd11', $single=true);`

You will get the updated value.

---

Updated function:

```
function woocommerce_send_notification( $user_id ){
    $body       = '';
    $to         = 'info@domain.com';    //address that will receive this email
    $subject    = 'One of your customers has updated their information.';

    update_meta_cache( 'user', $user_id ); // Bust existing cached user data

    $user      = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $user_name = $user->user_login;

    $body .= '<table>';
    $body .= '<tr><td><strong>' . __("Account") . '</strong></td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Username: </td><td>' . $user_name                                         . '</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>First name: </td><td>' . $user->billing_first_name . '</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Last name: </td><td>' . $user->billing_last_name  . '</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Phone: </td><td>' . get_field( 'user_phone', 'user_{$user_id}' ) . '</td></tr>';
    $body .= '<tr><td>Age: </td><td>' . get_field( 'user_age', 'user_{$user_id}' ) . '</td></tr>';
    $body .= '</table>';    

    //set content type as HTML
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;');

    //send email
    if( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers ) ){
        //echo 'email sent';
    }else{
        //echo 'email NOT sent';                
    }
    //exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tell me how to put `update_meta_cache('user', $user_id);`? Can you show this in my code example?

Comment: @Dmitry put it above the line `$user      = new WP_User( $user_id );`

Comment: I put the code where you said. All without changes. Apparently still cached.

Comment: And what about checkboxes? Everything is correct in the database, and in the email to the administrator shows “array” (

Comment: @Dmitry Which field is a checkbox? Check the value of the array returned.
If it's Age, do something like `$age = get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_age', $single=true); var_dump($age);` to figure out what's in the $age array. Chances are you'll just need to output `$age['value']` or `get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_age', true)['value']` or something like that.

Comment: Excuse me, could you show this in my code example? Thank you!

Comment: All values are stored correctly in the database. The word "Array" is displayed in the value of the checkboxes, only in the email of the administrator.

Comment: Any field with a checkbox. When selecting one checkbox, its value is correctly stored in the database. And in an email instead of a value, only the word "Array".

Comment: Can you help with this problem?

Comment: For example, the radio button is correctly stored in the database and also correctly displayed in the email to the administrator. The problem is only with the checkboxes. Unfortunately, I need only checkboxes.

Comment: If a checkbox field is appearing as `array()`, what's happening is that PHP is casting the data from an array to string when echoing it to the page. This happens because you can only echo strings. If there's an array, try this `echo $age_check = get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_age', $single=true); echo $age_check[0];` This will give you the first value of the array. These are fundamentals of PHP, and I can't help you much further if you don't understand them. Sorry.

Comment: Here is information on Type Juggling, which is related to casting an array to string (mentioned above): http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The database does not store "user_age", only "field_5b462d304b101". And, so that these lines are shown in the email, you need to specify $body.

Comment: In the PHP-code all this is correctly shown. But I need to show these values in an email to the administrator. Can you give an example based on my code?

Comment: `echo $age_check = get_user_meta($user_id, 'field_5b462d304b101', $single=true); echo $age_check[0];` I can't run your code specifically, so I don't know if this will work. This is all the help I can give. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how the string is being parsed whenever you pass the second parameter of `get_field()`. By using single quotes PHP interprets that as a string literal, so you won't be able to pass any PHP variables to the string. For example:

```
echo 'user_{$user_id}'; // Outputs: user_{$user_id}
```

But if user double quotes PHP will automatically escape and process:

```
echo "user_{$user_id"; // Outputs: user_123
```

So whenever you use `get_field()` it should look like this:

```
get_field( 'user_phone', "user_{$user_id}" );
```

Comment: As it turned out, this plugin "ACF for Woocommerce" saves the field data as meta_key: “field_5b7e4f388fd11” and meta_value: “+79998006655”. Tell me how to correctly display the fields in my code? `get_field( 'field_5b7e4f388fd11', "user_{$user_id}" )` This for some reason does not work. Emails come empty fields ((